# PHP lambda expression and anonymous function: What are the differences?

Tags: php, anonymous-function, lambda

In PHP, I've read that lambda expressions are simply anonymous functions. However, in reading lambda calculus materials, it seems that not just any anonymous function can be a lambda expression. For example:

```
$immutable = function($x)
{
   return $x * $x;
};

echo $immutable(2);
```

Results: 4

is a simple lambda expression.

However, the following anonymous function just does not seem very lambda-like:

```
$immutable = function($x)
{
   return "Hello " . $x;
};

echo $immutable("world");
```

Results: Hello world

Am I over-complicating the lambda calculus or is it the case that any anonymous function also a lambda expression?